# Web API Route not working properly in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-web-api-routing

This may be simple and its wierd and I cannot find out the reason why its hapenning.

I am using ASP.NET WEB API 2 Controller: I have a TransactionController, which suddenly stopped working after some modification in one of its action methods. I returned the code back, but its not working anymore.

All the other controllers are working normally. So, I decided two test it by creating two new controllers:

**ValueController**:

```
 public class ValueController : ApiController
    {
        public List<string> GetValues()
        {
            return new List<string>() { "1", "2"};
        }

        public List<string> GetValues (int ID)
        {
            return new List<string>() { "1", "2" };
        }
       public List<string> GetValues(int UserID, DateTime CreateDate)
       {
           return new List<string>() { "1", "2" };
       }
}
```

**TransactionController:**

```
 public class TransactionController : ApiController
{

    public List<string> GetTransaction(int ID)
    {
        return new List<string>() { "1", "2" };
    }
}
```

This my webApiConfig

```
  public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.EnableCors();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
```

**Global.asax**

```
  protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

        WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
    }
```

When requesting the item controller by the url:
*http://localhost:1607/api/value?ID=1*, its hitting the GetValues(int ID) action
and the other actions are working fine.

But, the problem is still with the TransactionController. When requesting it using the url: *http://localhost:1607/api/transaction?ID=1*. Its not hitting the action.

This the response of the request:
[image]

And Its returning back the index view page in the home controller.

[image]

Any thoughts why this might happen?

Comment: What are you route definitions?

Comment: @StephenMuecke, I included that in the question.

Comment: Do you have any other method decorations you didn't show. Look how functions named: GetValue(s ) but GetTransaction(?)

Comment: No that all the methods, I have created new controllers to investigate if that was happening and some route configuration is missing, but the problem resides only with the `transaction`. Regarding names, I guess the name of the method is not important, but the "get" is what it should be looking for.

Comment: You indicate that the problem controller / action is not getting 'hit' when you make the url request -- what does happen?  Don't you get an error message back from WebApi?  Perhaps something like: _No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI_

Comment: @DavidTansey I added the details requested

Comment: What if you call `http://localhost:1607/api/transaction/GetTransaction?ID=1`. It's been a while since I did any routing that wasn't attribute routing based, but don't you need to specify the action?

Comment: @h.salman have you tried enabling tracing? See [API tracing documentation here](https://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/testing-and-debugging/tracing-in-aspnet-web-api).